# How configure docker-compose.yaml to access host Postgres in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use Ubuntu 18, have an non-container Postgres database, installed on my machine, that I would like to connect from Docker container.

My current **docker-compose.yaml**:

```
version: "3"

services:
    ws-server:
        image: ws-server
        networks:
            - net-ws
        ports:
            - 2020:2020
    shortest-path:
        image: ws-client
        networks:
            - net-ws
        expose:
            - 5000
networks:
    net-ws:
```

Here I would like to add a configuration to be able to reach host database.

When I run my application with:

> docker run --rm -it --network=host ws-server

then all works properly.

So how to configure docker-compose.yaml to access host Postgres in Ubuntu 18?

Comment: use host ip from within the container, or setup a bridge and use that as the network. [access host service from docker](https://www.google.com/search?q=access+host+service+from+docker+site:stackoverflow.com) ... [etc](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-35-connect-to-a-database-running-on-your-docker-host)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I would think that should be much easier solution than these manipulations with docker0 interface

Comment: thats just one way, did you see https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-35-connect-to-a-database-running-on-your-docker-host `--net` can be defined in your compose file, your just not defining it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, this is a useful material. Thank you. If you give an exact answer it will be great (even if it is not about yaml file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 0):

As I see when use **host** mode there is no needs for other networks as all service ports are published. Also *networks* and *network_mode* can not be used together.

So the *docker-compose.yaml* that works:

```
version: "3"

services:
    ws-server:
        image: ws-server
        network_mode: host
        ports:
            - 2020:2020
    shortest-path:
        image: ws-client
        network_mode: host
        expose:
            - 5000
```

Now I can successfully access host Postgres database. However I would prefer access host database using also private (not host) network so that not publish unnecessary ports.